# Oracle Apex Interactive Report - cell background color

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.2

Is it possible remove white space (padding) inside cell?

Query return cell background color like this:

```
Select
'<span style="background-color: #B8817D">' || col_1 || '</span>' as "1",
'<span style="background-color: #B8817D">' || col_2 || '</span>' as "2",
'<span style="background-color: #F7DC6F">' || col_3 || '</span>' as "3",
'<span style="background-color: #F7DC6F">' || col_4 || '</span>' as "4"
.....
```

[image]

Comment: Have you hit F12 and used the browser's Inspect function to look at the CSS yet?

Comment: @MarkStewart Can't find anything to remove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires a bit of hacking, but it should work.

First add this page level inline CSS:

```css
.no-parent-padding {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: -12px -12px;
}

.yellow-background {
    background-clip: content-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 12px yellow;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.brown-background {
    background-clip: content-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 12px brown;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

Next the SELECT should look as follow:

```sql
select      
    '<div class="brown-background no-parent-padding">'|| 12 ||'</div>' AS "12",
    '<div class="yellow-background no-parent-padding">'|| 2 ||'</div>' AS "2"
....
```

Finally the result:
[image]

Comment: @Tnx for help but when have more columns it doesn't look like.  https://postimg.cc/8jh7jh3J

Comment: Edited (the CSS).... Check it now. I told you it was hacking :P

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to reference to this clean solution from Kutub Tech:
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fwrye5ES8mg) – [code to be found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16z3gaqM_SPEPkjmp3jEAxFkX4yHBeEoY/view)

**Steps**:

1. Select desired Column > go to "**Advanced**" > set "Static ID" > set **rep_col_diffcolor_1**
2. (optional) Select another Column > go to "**Advanced**" > set "Static ID" > set **rep_col_diffcolor_2**
3. Select Page Root > go to "**Inline**" > paste the following

```css
.a-IRR-table tr td[headers*="rep_col_diffcolor_1"] {
    background-color: #99ccff;
}
    
.a-IRR-table tr td[headers*="rep_col_diffcolor_2"] {
    background-color: #bfc4c9;
}
```